# Can't access redmine from other PC

Tags: iis, redmine

I followed this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/310678/Installing-Redmine-on-Windows-in-production to install redmine webapp (redmine.org) so I can use it for IIS.
I tried to access to the link from another PC but it gave me 404 error.
I am assuming that the problem is related to a configuration problem.
I don't know if I'm missing any step.
Any help!?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just reintall everything plus installing ruby project (Manual installation).
I followed these instruction http://www.helicontech.com/articles/installing-redmine-on-windows-in-production/
and it worked I don't know how!
Now I can access redmine from any other device inside the same network that the remine was installed in or by using VPN from outside the network.